# Recreating a Chapter Heading Style

Tags: sectioning, book-design, books

I've seen various responses to similar questions, but I haven't found one which helps me recreate the following simplistic header design in the `book` document class:

[image: Elementary Geometry]

This is taken from John Roe's *Elementary Geometry*. The main points I want to recreate here are the following:

1. The chapter heading is centred
2. The text is sans-serif for the chapter and also the heading/subheadings, but then the main text is in an ordinary serif font

I've read that point (2) can be achieved using the `scrartcl` package, but that requires changing the document class and I'd rather stick to `book`. Can anyone help recreate this setting?

Comment: It can easily be done with `titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard Can you refer me to a mwe?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about the strange indentation of normal  text?

Comment: @Johannes_B Are you asking why it's like that? The author leaves the space for theorem numbers, e.g. https://books.google.com.mt/books?id=Xmb44wyy7gEC&pg=PA11&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Ok, so the normal text isn't really indented (the text block is shifted). It is the chapter title, section title, theorem title etc. that is sticking out into the margin. You should add that information to the question, an answer relies on that information.

Comment: Side note: Switching from `book`  to `scrartcl` isn't a brilliant idea, but switching to  `scrbook` should need minor changes. A `titlesec` solution wouldn't really apply when using `scrbook`.

Comment: I don't really care for the indentation though, only the two points I mentioned (sans-serif title/headers, but serif text)

Comment: @Johannes_B So how could I achieve the sans-serif title/headers without changing the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code to emulate this layout:

```
\documentclass[11pt,]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\titlerule[1.5pt]\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\bigskip}{\thechapter}{1.5pc}{}[\vspace{2ex}{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-0.5\marginparwidth}{50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}{\thesection}{0.8em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.5\marginparwidth}{3.5ex}{2.3ex}%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Vector geometry}

\section{Affine spaces}
In Chapter 1, we explained how Euclid built up the whole of geometry from a small number of fundamental assumptions or \emph{axioms}. Following Euclid’s method, we stated nine axioms and from them developed the theory of \emph{vectors}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\hrule}{0pt}{\center\bfseries\thechapter\\[3ex]}[\endcenter\hrule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
alkasdjalsk laskj laskj ldsakj dl
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will have to tweak it for your usage though, ie for sans serif fonts you substitute `\bfseries` with `\sffamily`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\hrule}{0pt}{\center\sffamily\thechapter\\[3ex]}[\endcenter\hrule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
alkasdjalsk laskj laskj ldsakj dl
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]