Seek for help of a particular chapter design
Can anyone help me realize the chapter design shown in the figure? Thank you
I am trying to use usepackage titlesec, but I have trouble mimicking the style in the figure. The following is my code. Can someone help me to modify my code to obtain the style shown in the figure? And for these commands like \thechapter, \vspace, where can I find a reference for them?
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{5pt}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{6pt}\huge\MakeUppercase}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

Addition:
My latex template is \documentclass{book} and I am satisfied with @egreg's solution regarding the chapter design, but what can I do to adjust the header to the mid place and make the headers of all pages (no matter even or odd) centered and only show the section content?
The figure below is what I want to have (mainly the red circles)

But what I got is by default from the book template, see figure below  where one can see

the headers are not centered;
pages from odd and even show different header content.


Can you provide a complete compilable example which demonstrates a single problem you are having as you attempt to implement the design you want? Without code, your question isn't really answerable.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369443/recreating-a-chapter-heading-style?rq=1 (From the links on the right.)

@cfr Thank you for your comments, and I just update my post.

Could you complete it so  people can compile it? I avoid titlesec, but lots of people like it, I know. For the commands you mention, any standard introduction to LaTeX can provide details and examples.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/ provides a list of introductory resources for LaTeX.

Basically, \thechapter formats the current chapter number e.g. 1 or VI or D and \vspace{} adds vertical space if it's appropriate according to LaTeX's algorithms e.g. not at the top of a page.

@cfr Thank you again for quick response. I am sort of familiar with the usage of  the latex, but how to code, I have not much experience, e.g., those commands I listed. Do you have some clue about references w.r.t. the code level.

You didn't follow that link did you? You'll find a range of answers there, most explaining the scope of the source they're pointing to. A good introduction to LaTeX explains the basics of customisation and that certainly includes the commands you asked about. Just don't use the top answer in the list - as the answer itself explains, that particular resource has not aged well and isn't reliable. I like Kopka and Daly, It is still good, but there are better methods for lots of things now so one of the other choices is likely better.

There's also usrguide & clsguide, which you likely have already, but they are references rather than introductions.

You're not too far…
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}% it's already in the class
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {%
   \filleft\normalfont\bfseries
   \vspace{-\topskip}\titlerule[2pt]%
   \vspace{1pc}%
  }
  {\fontsize{3.5cm}{0}\selectfont\thechapter}
  {5pt}
  {\vspace{6pt}\huge\MakeUppercase}
  [{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {%
   \filleft\normalfont\bfseries
   \vspace{-\topskip}\titlerule[2pt]%
   \vspace{1pc}%
  }
  {\fontsize{3.5cm}{0}\selectfont\vphantom{0}}
  {5pt}
  {\vspace{6pt}\huge\MakeUppercase}
  [{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

Text at the beginning of the chapter.
Text at the beginning of the chapter.
Text at the beginning of the chapter.
Text at the beginning of the chapter.
Text at the beginning of the chapter.

\end{document}

The oneside option is just for showing unnumbered and numbered chapters in the same picture.
If you use a scalable font (not the standard one), you don't need fix-cm.

By replacing the two occurrences of \filleft with \filcenter, you get the following.


May I ask why do we need % to do line break?

@hmeng A line break is a space.

Oh, I forget to mention that the centering head is also one of the thing I wanna realize, but I have no clue about to use it. I checked fancyhdr document, but is totally lost

@hmeng Change the two occurrences of \filleft with \filcenter. I added the output in my answer.

@egreg Maybe my statement is misleading, what I mean is the header design. (the very first lane in my figure page 2)  How can I get a similar header as the figure shown? Thank you !

@hmeng Sorry, but I don't understand. Isn't the first realization the same as your picture?

@egreg Sorry I did not make myself clear, so I edited my post. Please check the Addition part.

@hmeng That's a completely different question and doesn't involve titlesec.

@egreg I can raise another question and hope you could help
